# how to change std flag of clang in mac? current clang version 10.0.1 is using c++98 flag

Tags: macos, c++11, clang++, llvm-clang, compiler-flags

Though documentation of clang says version 10.0.1 uses c++11 but I am trying to compile c++ programs using clang compiler and clang compiler explicitly need -std=c++11 flag to compile with c++11 version.Otherwise it gives error in codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the documentation might mean is that new XCode projects have these `std=c++11` flags burried in their configuration by default. This doesn't necessarily mean that the command-line `clang++` executable uses this as a default.

You can create an alias, e.g.

```
alias clang++="clang++ -std=c++11"
```

to circumvent this issue for ad-hoc command line usage. Within real projects, you will have to maintain the build settings and compiler flags anyhow, so adding your desired C++ standard flag should be a simple task.